# How to Proxy Built-In JS Object?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy, built-in-types

I want to proxy some built in object primitives in JS, for example, “Number” or “String” object wrappers. However it seems the Proxy object ends up reporting as a normal JS object when passed to some native functions.

```js
const n = new Number(10);
const p = new Proxy(n, {});
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.bind(n)()); // [object Number]
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.bind(p)()); // [object Object]
```

This is just one example where the proxy gets treated differently than its target. This different treatment seems to happen whenever the proxy is passed to a function implemented in native code.

Is it possible to get the proxied object to be treated as its target object even when passed to such functions like Object.protocol.toString?

Comment: "*I want to proxy some built in object primitives in JS*" - just curious, but why? Why are you even using primitive object wrappers?

Comment: @Bergi I found a workaround. I set the prototype of a builtin object to a proxy which was enough for my situation. And I'm trying to implement JS in JS for fun. I'd love help if you're interested https://github.com/joehinkle11/SandboxedJS

Comment: @Bergi for testing, it can be convenient to intercept properties of an object. Trying to set the prototype of Object.prototype with a Proxy is not possible. Is there another way?